# Convert string to float: "8.9km" to float

Tags: java

I'm getting the distance in string like "8.9km". I need to convert it to float.

So if the string is "8.9km", the corresponding float will be 8.9

How to achieve this in Java?

Note: The value can change to miles/meters also, since it is retrieved from Google Maps

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to split a text file into words?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/649407/how-to-split-a-text-file-into-words)

Comment: @Siddharth Wrong question...

Comment: You have to do it in two steps: remove the "km" part; then parse the float http://javarevisited.blogspot.it/2013/08/how-to-parse-string-to-float-in-java-to-float-example.html

Comment: remove km than Float.parseFloat(string)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7552660/java-convert-float-to-string-and-string-to-float

Comment: Should this be `8.9` or `8900`? i.e. should it read the `k` as well?  BTW don't use `float` unless there is a very good reason `double` has close to one billion times the accuracy.

Comment: @PeterLawrey he stated that the output for this example should be `8.9`

Comment: @bcsb1001 I guess I am hinting that is likely to be a bad idea if you want to support meters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the following code,

```
String dis = "8.9km";
Float distance = Float.valueof(dis.substring(0,dis.indexOf("km")));
float d = distance.floatValue();
```

Comment: You did not write how to remove the "km" part of the string

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
String distance = "8.9km";
float distanceInFloat = Float.parseFloat(distance.substring(0,distance.indexOf("km")));
System.out.println(distanceInFloat);
```

Output :

```
8.9
```

Comment: Please create a float variable to make the example more clear

Comment: But this will parse a float even if 'km' is in the middle of the string e.g. "1.5km Some Text" will return 1.5 with your method, despite it clearly being invalid input.

Comment: @bcsb1001 OP has clearly stated `I'm getting the distance in string like "8.9km".` and I have answered based on that. Question says nothing otherwise. Validation if any should be taken care separately.

Answer (score 1):

Use following code:

```
    String s="8.9km";
    s=s.replace("km", "");
    float f=Float.parseFloat(s);
    System.out.println(f);
```

**Output:**

```
8.9
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: But then an invalid input string, such as "1km.km5", will be parsed as "1.5", despite clearly being invalid input.

Comment: In that case spilt from "." and then go ahead.

Answer (score 1):

try the following for removing all non-digits(excluding '.') from a string

```
String distance = "7.9km";
float floatValue = Float.parseFloat(distance.replaceAll("[^\\d.]",""));
System.out.println(floatValue);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
String str = "8.9km";
str = (str.replace("km", ""); //remove the km
float f = Float.parseFloat(str); //convert the string to a float
```

The float f will now have a value of 8.9

```
System.out.println(f);
```

Output:

```
8.9
```

Comment: The value can change to miles/meters also, since it is retrieved from Google Maps

Comment: @webgenius you can use try/catch `try { str = (str.replace("km", "");  str = (str.replace("miles", ""); str = (str.replace("meters", ""); } catch (Exception e) { }` Then you will have your string without the km, miles or meters, as although it will not be able to do two of the three statements, it will be able to do the other one, and the try/catch stops the other two from causing errors.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public float parse(String string, String suffix) { // suffix can be m, km etc.
    if (!string.endsWith(suffix)) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException();
    }
    string = string.subString(0, string.length() - suffix.length()); // get rid of the suffix we have at the end
    return Float.parseFloat(string); // parse the float from what we have left
}
```

If the float is invalid, or the string doesn't end in "km", a `NumberFormatException` or `IllegalArgumentException` will be thrown, respectively.

Answer (score 1):

Try this.. i hope it will help

```
String km = "8.9km";
float kmInFloat=Float.parseFloat(km.replaceAll("km",""));
System.out.println(kmInFloat);
```

Output :
    8.9